# Can WinRS access UNC paths?

Tags: windows, batch-file, winrm, winrs

I'm using WinRS to run an executable on a remote machine. That executable, in turn, needs to access a UNC network share. I'm on a Windows network with AD, and running everything as a domain admin account (not a local account) that is a machine admin of the servers in question, and has Full Control (folder and share) of the network share. But when I use WinRS to run a remote process, that remote process doesn't seem to have network access. The simplest example I could distill it down to is:

```
winrs -r:RedServer dir \\BlueServer\SomeSharedFolder
```

which gives the error

> Access is denied.

Note that WinRS itself works on RedServer, because this runs fine:

```
winrs -r:RedServer dir C:
```

So, it sounds like a permissions issue, right? But to prove this account does have Full Control over the `\\BlueServer\SomeSharedFolder` share, I logged into RedServer with that same account and ran this at the command prompt there:

```
dir \\BlueServer\SomeSharedFolder
```

It ran fine, giving me the contents of that folder. It's only the combination of WinRS + UNC path that causes errors.

Is there something I need to configure differently, or is this a limitation/safeguard of Windows? I experienced a similar limitation with Sysinternals' PsExec.exe; I could access anything on the target machine, but nothing on the network. Incidentally, I found a somewhat-related SO question here: "[Error when creating mapped drive using winrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652236/error-when-creating-mapped-drive-using-winrs)", but no answers there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you describe is a double hop scenario which requires additional configuration on the client and server to support. A double hop scenario is remotely logging in to a Windows server and then accessing a remote network share:

`client -> server -> file share`

You can accomplish this via [CredSSP or Kerberos delegation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309365(v=vs.85).aspx).

> CredSSP authentication is intended for environments where Kerberos delegation cannot be used. Support for CredSSP was added to allow a user to connect to a remote server and have the ability to access a second-hop machine, such as a file share.

While I haven't tried these instructions, they seem like a reasonable place to start. Additionally [this blog post](http://www.travisgan.com/2014/03/enable-powershell-double-hop-remoting.html) by Travis Gan appears to be helpful.